# Getting (and keeping) extended permissions in a facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using an fb login button on a site, and our app needs extended permissions: publish_stream. When the user logs in, we can get the permissions, get an access_token, and publish various items to their stream.

However, the site doesn't seem to know if the user's logged in to facebook or not, and I'm having to allow permissions on subsequent visits to the page. However, if I hit the website, I get the access_token - but I'm the admin of the facebook app.

Is there a way to get permissions and have them persist, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you *might* need to request the "[offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/#extended_perms)" extended permission (if you want to make API calls after a normal access token would have expired). I'm not sure this is what you need though - this is for making API calls as a user while the user is not logged in to Facebook anymore.

It sounds like your Application is not properly using the API to check if the user is logged in or not. Without seeing any code I can't tell what is happening, but if you are using the API correctly once a user has authorized your application, they should be able to make API calls via your App while they are logged in to Facebook. Unless you changed application's on them, they will not need to re-authorize the permissions.

Please edit your question to provide more details if this does not help, and good luck.